# $S=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x^2+y^2=z^2, z \geq 0\}$ is not regular surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose $S$ is a regular surface. There exists coordinate function $\textbf x:U \to S \cap V,$ for some open $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ and some open $V \subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$.  WLOG, let $(0,0,0) \in S \cap V$ and $\textbf x(u,v)=\left(f(u,v), g(u,v),\sqrt {(f(u,v))^2+(g(u,v))^2}\right)$ for some smooth $f,g:U \to \mathbb{R}.$

Could anyone advise me on how to prove that  $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial u}\sqrt {(f(u,v))^2+(g(u,v))^2}=\dfrac{f_{u}f+g_{u}g}{\sqrt{f^2+g^2}}$ is not smooth at some $(x,y) \in U?$

Answer (score 0):

The idea would be to take  $V$ s.t. $(0,0,0)\in S\cap V$, $U\subset \mathbb R^2$. Suppose there is a diffeomorphism $f:U\to S\cap V$. WLOG, $f(0)=0$. Take any $C^1$ curve in $U$ passing through zero with non-zero speed. Its image under $f$ will be smooth, too. Yet it would pass through "the pointy end" of $S$ with non-zero speed, therefore the image can't be smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Any parametrization will fail obviously at $(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)$ (the vertex of the cone). As
$$x=f(u,v),\qquad y=g(u,v),$$
take $(u_0,v_0)$ s.t.
$$0=f(u_0,v_0),\qquad 0=g(u_0,v_0),$$
and the denominator $\sqrt{f^2+g^2}$ will be zero.

EDIT: all the above is true but not enough.

The partial derivatives of $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ does not exists at (0,0):

$$
{\partial z\over\partial x}(0,0)=
\lim_{x\to 0}{\sqrt{x^2+0^2}-\sqrt{0^2+0^2}\over x}=
\lim_{x\to 0}{|x|\over x}.
$$
(lateral limits are $\ne$)

Comment: But the numerator is $0$ too.

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: True! Special reasoning using the *definition* of partial derivative is required. See the answer by TZakrevskiy. Is enogh to prove that the partial derivatives of $z=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ does not exists at (0,0).

Comment: Thank you. Why does it suffice to prove that partial derivatives of $z$ doesn't exist at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Any two parametrizations are related by a diffeomorphism.